# Devexpress grid (2.11) showing extra space above header(wpf/xaml)

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, master-detail, devexpress-wpf

I am getting extra space while using GridControl.DetailDescriptor in dev express grid (2.11 )
.I have made  even it is showing extra space with message "Drag a column header here to group by that column...".I am using grid for Master/Detail data.Also AutoPopulateColumns="False" for both master/child.

VS 2010 is dev enviroment.

Thanks for any help/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code inside dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor

```
<dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
<dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding ursource}">

 <dxg:GridControl>
......
<dxg:GridControl.View>
  <dxg:TableView  AutoWidth="True" AllowBestFit="True"  ShowGroupPanel="False" />
 </dxg:GridControl.View>

</dxg:GridControl>
</dxg:DataControlDetailDescriptor>
 </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
```

Comment: Why were both the question and answer downvoted? They were exactly what I needed.